# How to remove property namespace out of powershell output?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I think I might be searching for the wrong thing as I can't find an answer to this. Basically I run `Get-Process` and select some properties in PowerShell. I get the info I want however for one of the properties, `MainModule` it is including the `System.Diagnostics.Processmodule` namespace and I only want the filename.

Could anyone explain why this is happening and how I can get rid of it please? I am new to PowerShell and like I said I can't find an answer.

The command I am running:

```
Get-Process | select id, processname, starttime, mainmodule | ft -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
  Id ProcessName       StartTime           MainModule                                 
  -- -----------       ---------           ----------                               
1788 armsvc            22/01/2016 07:36:31 System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (armsvc.exe)
```

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnF6m.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a calculated property.

```
Get-Process | Select-Object `
  Id,
  ProcessName,
  StartTime,
  @{Name="ModuleName"; Expression={$_.MainModule.ModuleName}}
```